# In GIMP is there a way to make selection start from the canvas border?

Tags: gimp, selections, canvas

In GIMP when I want to crop a rectangular image down to a square there's something frustrating about how the Rectangle Select Tool behaves. Even though I can constrain the proportions of the selection by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> as I drag it out, the selection frustratingly begins *outside* of the canvas instead of at the border. This defeats the purpose of proportional selection because as you can see below, the selection does not end up being square:

[image: GIMP: Square selection is not square]

**Edit:**
The best solution I've found is to enable **View > Snap to Canvas Edges** and click as close to the edge as possible when beginning the selection. But is there a setting that can be changed to make the selection start at the canvas edges even if you began drawing the selection marquee outside the canvas?

Answer (score 6):

For both rectangle selection and crop tool: use *View>Snap to canvas edges*, then click sufficiently close to a corner (IIRC 8 pixels or less, by default) and your selection will start exactly on the corner.

Also, once you have a selection, if you release the button and move towards the center of the selection, you get a crossed arrows pointer that says that you can just move the selection by clicking and dragging it. If the *Snap to canvas edges* option is active the selection will align on the edges if you get sufficiently close.

Comment: Thanks! I literally figured out how to Snap to Canvas Edges as you were answering me, so I reworded part of my question - sorry. The additional tips in your answer are helpful too.